# How do I phrase a thank you and acceptance for an exclusive invitation?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

I recently received an invitation to participate in a professional summit. It is an invite only summit and very exclusive and I am not sure how to word my response. Is it more appropriate to say

> I am very honored to have been given an invitation and would like to let you know that I will be attending the summit in February.

or

> I am honored to have received an invitation and would like to let you know I plan on attending in February.

or something else entirely?

What is the most graceful way to accept the invitation and show my gratitude for being invited in the first place?

Comment: You show your gratitude with "Thank you (very much)".

Comment: http://www.samplelettersworld.com/sample-letters/acceptance-letters/1535-accept-a-formal-invitation-to-a-social-event-sample-letter-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use 'would like to let you know'. It is very annoying and usually higher-ups 'let us know'.

I am very honored to receive an invitation and I will be attending the summit in February. Thank you very much.

This should be enough. No need to stress too much about it.